# Why does create.js always execute all the code, in spite of if statements being included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app I have key_contacts where you can add phone_numbers via a modal. The key_contacts are displayed on both Company show page and Sales_Opportunity show page in a table. When a user adds a new phone number for the key_contact, I'm using Jquery to reload the table so the newly added phone_number is now shown.

This worked fine until I wanted to do it across two different pages, because the key_contacts on the sales_opportunity show page are only those associated with that sales_opportunity, whereas those on the company show page are all contacts belonging_to the company.

Unless a sales_opportunity exists, the code breaks when adding a phone_number to a key_contact in the company view because there is no sales_opportunity object, and therefore there is no way to render the @sales_opportunity.key_contact. The solution to this would be to have create.js.erb understand which page it's being called from, and then only render the table relevant to that view.

My create.js.erb file:

```
    //update the key contact table with the new phone number, and close the modal
$('#phone_number_modal').modal('hide')
                    .clear_previous_errors();
resetForm($('#new_phone_number'));
$input = $('#phone_number_error');
$input.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').find('.warning-block').html('');
//render the newly added key contact to the table if the AJAX call succeeded
if (window.location.href.indexOf("companies") > -1) {
    $('#key-contacts-table-div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/key_contacts_table')%>");
}
if (window.location.href.indexOf("sales_opportunities") > -1) {
    $('#key-contacts-table-div-2').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'sales_opportunities/key_contacts_table')%>");
}
    $('.alert').remove();
    $('#key-contacts').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
    });
```

This doesn't work - in spite of being on the companies route, the create.js.erb file STILL renders the sales_opportunities/key_contacts_table into the view, and still returns a 500 error because the Company does not yet have a sales_opportunity.

As an aside, if I comment out the line:

```
//$('#key-contacts-table-div-2').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'sales_opportunities/key_contacts_table')%>");
```

It also still runs that code for some reason. I have to physically delete that line of code for the jquery to run correctly.

I know my create.js.erb is not an elegant piece of jquery, but I need this to work. Can anyone help me fix it please?

Comment: Are you sure that this file is even being executed at all?  Put some `console.log` in there to check.

Comment: Do you understand that when you comment out Javascript in a js.erb file, the Ruby in that commented out line will still get run? I think that may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - I know the javascript is running because I have used some console.log events, and because when I delete the offending line it works as intended (on the companies page).

Comment: @Trosborn - I did not know the Ruby would still execute. Is there a way to comment out this kind of code in a js.erb file, or do I just need to delete the line every time I want to test what happens without it?

Comment: To comment out Ruby you need to use a #. <%# escape_javascript

Comment: Thanks for the info - I had wondered why that wasn't being commented out!